# How to refresh jsp page?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm new to Google App Engine and I'm having a little problem that I can't seem to be able to find the solution to.

Whenever I create/delete/update something from the Datastore, in the end I do this:

```
resp.sendRedirect("/view_list.jsp");
```

And the page doesn't get updated.

For instance, if I have a page with a list of 2 items, then I create another item and I redirect to that page with the list, and instead of showing 3 items, it shows 2 items, until I change page and come back.

So how can I make sure that the page refreshes after my changes to the Datastore?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points that are relevant:

- The Data store is HRD (High Replication Database) and as per the documentation, the delay from the time a write is committed until it becomes visible in all datacenters means that queries across multiple entity groups (non-ancestor queries) can only guarantee eventually consistent results. Consequently, the results of such queries may sometimes fail to reflect recent changes to the underlying data. Please refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency?csw=1) for more details.
- In short, to get consistent reads, use `get` as much as you can. If you use a query, there could be a delay due to the indexing.

Hope this helps. I also suggest to frame the question title better. The question is a good one but could get lost when it says "refresh the jsp page".

Comment: Agreed. What's described sounds like an eventual consistency issue that's common when not using ancestors on write and queries. I've seen the same happen when using Python.